How can I show that $\|\,|A|\,|A^*|\,\|=\|A^2\|$?
I have a question regarding certain equalities.
How can I show that $$\|\,|A|\,|A^*|\,\|=\|A^2\|$$ where $A$ is a bounded linear operator, and $|A|=(A^*A)^{1/2}$.
I have tried using $\|A^*A\|=\|A\|^2$ but I didn't get very far.
Any idea?

We need the following identities: $\|B^* B\| = \|B B^*\| = \|B\|^2$. Using them several times we get:
\begin{align*}
\| \;|A|\; |A^*|\; \|^2 &= \| \; |A| \; |A^*|\; |A^*| \; |A| \;\|\\
& = \| \; |A| A A^* |A|\; \| \\
&= \| (|A|A) (|A|A)^*\| \\
&= \| (|A|A)^*(|A|A)\| \\
&= \|A^* |A|\;|A| A\| \\
&= \|A^* A^* A A\| \\
&= \|(A^2)^* A^2\| = \|A^2\|^2
\end{align*}

We can apply the polar decomposition. We have $$A=U|A|,\ |A|=U^*A,\\A^*=V|A^*|,\,|A^*|=V^*A^* =AV$$ where $U$ and $V$ are partial isometries. Then $$A^2=U|A|(V|A^*|)^*=U|A|\,|A^*|V^* \\ |A|\,|A^*|=U^*A^2V$$ These two identities imply $$\|A^2\|\le \||A|\,|A^*|\|,\,||A|\,|A^*|\|\le\|A^2\|$$ respectively.
